# What's the point of prefixing a sentence with "Please be advised that"?

Tags: phrase-usage

What's the point of prefixing a sentence with "Please be advised that"?

Example:

[image]

Couldn't the first sentence have simply started with "Your application for research utilizing human subjects […]"?

Comment: It's just an _imperative passive,_ formal and pseudo-legal way of presenting a report, conclusion, or finding. It could be omitted, of course.

Comment: It is also a polite way of saying "You should know that"...

Comment: It is a good example of people working in certain businesses or government agencies who don't know how to write without using awkward, stilted phrasing. In short,  it's business English from 50 years ago still being used today.

Comment: Wow. This letter seems like a parody of ugly bureaucratese: 

please be advised that, utilizing, above named, such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general . . .

When you write something for an audience, you usually want that audience not only to understand what you're saying, but also to feel that they have a complete understanding of what you're saying. To this end, it is often helpful to use various phrases that don't really affect the meaning of a given sentence, but that shape its interpretation by precluding, or at least discouraging, unintended readings.

For example, I recently saw a parking lot that was closed off, with a sign saying that it was "closed until further notice". On the face of it, this is silly; the "further notice" would probably just take the form of reopening the lot and removing the sign. So why not just say that it's "closed"? Well, because "closed" would mean "closed, and we're inconsiderate jerks who haven't thought about the fact that you probably want to know when (and whether) it will reopen", whereas "closed until further notice" means "closed, and we would tell you when it would reopen, except that we're not sure yet". (To be sure, "until further notice" is not the best wording they could have used, and the overall effect was a bit funny; but it served its purpose.)

In your specific case . . .

I think "Please be advised that …" here means roughly "We are a formal bureaucratic institution invested with sober decision-making authority, and …". One reason to include it is that the rest of the letter has some bureaucratic instructions that they want Dr. Bergeron to take seriously. If they just say "Congratulations! Your application is approved!", that invites him to treat it casually.

That said, the overall effect seems like overkill; it's already an obviously bureaucratic memo (did you notice that even the *letterhead* talks about "compliance" and "policy"?), and since the message is a positive one, they probably don't need to worry so much about Dr. Bergeron reacting immaturely. The bland facelessness is probably more important in the alternative version, that probably begins something like

> Please be advised that your application for research utilizing human subjects has been carefully reviewed by the above named committee, but has not been approved at this time, for one or more of the following reasons:
>
> - In our estimation, the research value of your project does not warrant the great likelihood of severe harm to your subjects and their families.
> - Although we agree with your statement that no one would participate in your research if they were informed beforehand of what it would entail, we have concluded, pursuant to 45 CFR 46, section 12, clause 38, and 45 CFR 46, section 12, clause 39, that this is not, in itself, sufficient justification for removing the usual requirement for informed consent.
> - In light of University policy, we cannot accept any research plan that performs a procedure on human beings in order to gauge whether it is safe to perform it on mice. To the contrary, University policy demands unconditionally that, wherever possible, a procedure be tested on animal models before being considered for use in people.
> - Your application was printed on 8.5x11" paper, double-spaced, and stapled at the upper-left-hand corner. It is the policy of this committee that all applications must be submitted on A4 paper, 1.75x-spaced, and stapled at the upper-right-hand corner, in order to promote efficient filing and easily distinguish them from ordinary documents at the University. This policy is strictly enforced.
>
> This decision is binding, but may be appealed. If you would like to challenge it, […]